# Inverse Laplace transform of transfer function with infinite poles

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I'm trying to get the inverse Laplace transform of the following transfer function:

$$
\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\bigl[F(s)\bigl] =\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\biggl[\frac{\tanh\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{s}-\tanh \sqrt{s}}\biggl] = \mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\biggl[\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}\coth \sqrt{s} -1}\biggl] 
$$

I numerically verified that the denominator has an infinite zeros, $s_j \in \mathbb{R}_{\leq0}$, so I expect a solution of the type:

$$
\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\bigl[F(s)\bigl]= \sum_{j}^\infty \operatorname{Res} \left(F(s)\exp [st],s_j \right)
$$

However, I am struggling with the evaluation of the residues, starting from  $s_0 = 0$ :
$$
\operatorname{Res} \left(F(s)\exp [st],s_0 \right) = \lim_{s~\to~0} \biggl[\frac{se^{st}}{\sqrt{s}\coth \sqrt{s} -1}\biggl] 
$$

What is the best method to evaluate this and other $s_j$ limits?

Comment: To evaluate the limit, use the Laurent series for $\coth$

Answer (score 1):

This question is identical to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119402/inverse-laplace-transform-of-fs-frac1-sqrts-coth-sqrts-1/4180710#4180710).
So I refer you to the anwer that I gave there.

Comment: If you have the reputation, it is better to close as a duplicate.